# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1708391' for key 'PRIMARY' magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm getting this error and it is keeping me busy all day. I get it when I log in on the admin page. The magento version is 1.7

things I have undertaken so far (among the things I still can remember)

```
clear browser cache
clear cache (db & files)
clear sessions
clear locks
```

but not work!!!

Comment: Did you install the some extensions before it?

Comment: Do you have the full error message? Or at least can you show the stack trace?